# Unable to load data in subgrid

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid

When I open the URL as -> `http://localhost:9000/` the subgrid loads the data. But when it open the same page from URL as -> `http://172.21.123.172:9000/` the subgrid doesn't loads.

**172.21.123.172  is mapped to localhost**

I have checked it on IE9 using developer tool and in network I can see data in both the cases but subgrid doesn't show the data in later case.

In chrome it is working fine.

I don't know what m doing wrong.I just got stuck with this. And m not getting any error when debugging the script.

Or Is there a difference between the HTTPRequest from localhost and IPAddress mapped to localhost. If so how to resolve it.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**edited**

The ajax is used to load the data in subgrid

```
subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
    var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
    subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
    pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
    $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");
    jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
        url:"/loadNotificationGrid?id="+row_id,
        datatype: "json",
```

Comment: If you're using ajax to load the data, you'll need to make the ajax call to the same domain (or IP) that you used to load the page. This is due to cross origin restrictions.

Comment: Yes m using Ajax to load data in subgrid. And m using same domain (or IP) to load the page as well as subgrid.

Comment: @Jason P : any suggestion?